# string reverse in C++

Tags: c++, c, string

I found this piece of code on the site, it seems the author is long gone, anyway, I'm having hard time understanding the actual swap and how the reverse occurs:

```
void strrev2(char *str)
{
        if( str == NULL )
                return;

        char *end_ptr = &str[strlen(str) - 1];
        char temp;
        while( end_ptr > str )
        {
                temp = *str;
                *str++ = *end_ptr;
                *end_ptr-- = temp;
        }
}
```

let's say you feed it word "testing"

First iteration:

```
*end_ptr = 'g';

temp = 't'
*str = 'g' // is it first assigned and then incremented to point to the next location?
*end_ptr = 't' // is it first assigned and then decremented to point to the previous location?
```

What happens on the second iteration? I'm having hard time because I thought that on this line:

```
char *end_ptr = &str[strlen(str) - 1];
```

`end_ptr` will only contain address of one letter, so how can `*end_ptr` work?

Anyway, if someone can explain this to me in some graphical way..
Thanks.

Comment: I've added a C tag. Although technically this is C++ code, reversing a string in C++ is a one-liner.

Answer (score 23):

`str` and `end_ptr` are just pointers to the start and end of the string. Each time round the loop their characters are swapped, and they are each moved one step towards the middle of the string. When they meet (or cross), the loop terminates.

Here's a picture...

```
1. testing        s is str
   ^     ^        e is end_ptr
   s     e

2. gestint
    ^   ^
    s   e

3. gnitset
      ^
      se

4. done!
```

(By the way, this is the start of a common interview question at companies that think brain-teasers make good interview questions. The question inevitably continues... so now, how would you use the same principle to reverse the words in a sentence, without reversing the letters in each word?)

Answer (score 8):

I liked Alex's art and I wanted to elaborate a little more, so this is a little more drawn version out of that same explanation that every one else has been posting.

To Start off:

`|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'g'|'\0'| str  |      |      |
  ^                              | 0x00 |      |      |
 str`

Then after the line

`char *end_ptr = &str[strlen(str) - 1];`

since the strlen(str) returns 7,
`end_ptr = &str[6]`
So:

`|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'g'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
  ^                       ^      | 0x00 | 0x06 |      |
 str                     end`

once it enter the loop it checks to see that end is a bigger address than str, and then assigns the value at the address str is pointing to to temp:

`|'t'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'g'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
  ^                       ^      | 0x00 | 0x06 |  't' |
 str                     end`

It then continues by assigning the value at end to the address at str:

`|'g'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'g'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
  ^                       ^      | 0x00 | 0x06 |  't' |
 str                     end`

Then advances the pointer str to the next address

`|'g'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'g'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
      ^                   ^      | 0x01 | 0x06 |  't' |
     str                 end`

Assigns the value of temp to the address at end:

`|'g'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'t'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
      ^                   ^      | 0x01 | 0x06 |  't' |
     str                 end`

Then finally decrements end and loops back to the top of the while statement:

`|'g'|'e'|'s'|'t'|'i'|'n'|'t'|'\0'| str  | end  | temp |
      ^               ^          | 0x01 | 0x05 |  't' |
     str             end`

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to update the value of `temp` in your example

Comment: OMG, it evolves into a nice ascii-art contest!

Comment: So why is it takes so long to update temp? Is algorithm that bad? ;-)

Comment: Chezz, you sounds like enterprise programmer — a nice picture and no sense. 55 minutes and pictures aren't edited into shape ;-)

Comment: Am I missing something? It's only to the bottom of the first itteration... Man I really hope I am not doing that "blind to glaring retartion stare" thing I do when I code at 2 am with no more caffine in sight. :|

Answer (score 4):

The pointers are incremented and decremented after assignment, so the start pointer runs through the word as the end pointer runs backwards.

in "testing", first iteration exchanges "t" and "g", second iteration exchanges "e" and "n", and so on until the pointers meet at the middle of the word.

Answer (score 2):

First it swaps the first and the last, at the same time incrementing pointer to the first element so that it points to the second and decrementing pointer to the last, so that it points to last but one. It continues this way as long as the "last" character comes after the "first". When it's not the case it's done.

And no, I'm not good ascii artist, so no graphics for you.

Answer (score 2):

Side note: this is a lot easier to do:

```
#include <algorithm>
void strrev2(char *str)
{
    std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: -1 for not getting the point, not paying attention to the `c` tag and generally suggesting to quit smoking when asked how to get to the subway station.

Comment: -1 for myself for not knowing that c tag has been added later. Sorry man, but still -1 for you as well.

Comment: Wow hacker. Nice job admitting that you're wrong and not doing anything to apologize.

Comment: rlbond, I agree with hacker, you're not answering the question. Your answer could have easily been a comment. Not to mention your code is incorrect (drop "- 1").

Comment: rlbond, I haven't done anything *to apologize*, I actually *did* apologize, that' what "Sorry man" stands for. Like I said, I *am* sorry and I *would* reverse my downvote if it's been the primary reason for downovoting.