# help on code improvement and time effiency

Tags: c++, performance

I wrote a program that reverses each word in a string.  For example hello and goodbye is turned into olleh dna eybdoog.  My program works, however the time efficiency is o(n^2) and I probably could of written less code.  I am trying not to use any of the string.functions() ( I used string.length() once).  Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void breakString(string& me, char * otherOne, int len, int count);
void reverseString(char* s); 
 int main () {
string me=("hello and goodbye");
char * otherOne;
int len=0;
int count=0;

for (len; len<me.length()+1; len++){
    count++;
    if (me[len]=='\0') {
        otherOne=new char[count];
        len-=count-1;
        count=0;
        for (len; me[len]; len++){
            otherOne[count]=me[len];
            count++;
        }
        reverseString(otherOne);
        breakString( me, otherOne, len, count);
    }
    if (me[len]==' ' ) {
        otherOne=new char[count];
        len-=count-1;
        count=0;
for (len; me[len] != ' '; len++){
    otherOne[count]=me[len];
    count++;
}
reverseString(otherOne);
        breakString( me, otherOne, len, count);
        count=0;
        otherOne=NULL;
        delete[]otherOne;
    }

}
delete[]otherOne;
cout << me;
return 0;
}
void reverseString(char* s)  
{

int len =0;
char swap;
for (len=0; s[len] != '\0'; len++);

for ( int i=0; i<len/2; i++)
{

    swap = *(s+i);

    *(s+i)= *(s+len-i-1);

    *(s+len-i-1) = swap;


}
}


void breakString(string &me, char * otherOne, int len, int count){
len-=count;
for (count=0; otherOne[count]; count++){
    me[len]=otherOne[count];
    len++;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [string reverse in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461373/string-reverse-in-c)

Comment: You realize that std::string has a reverse iterator, right?  Why not just iterate from me.rebegin()?

Comment: @Paul - Not a duplicate.  That one reverses the entire string; Aaron's looking for a word-by-word reverser.

Comment: The concepts are similar enough - all he has to do is get a pointer to the beginning and end of each word and reverse them in place using the code in the references question.

Comment: I am trying not to use the std::string.

Comment: This obviously homework, it should be tagged as such and refine your question.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the reference. I looked at the code and it seem very similar to my reverseString function.  What is the difference?

Comment: Ed, its not homework, I am preparing for an interview.  I probably should of added interview tag.

Comment: I'm impressed to see those new + delete in the original. O(n^2) may even be much more if your memory is badly broken up. The allocation is generally very fast, the free is often very slow when you start having many small buffers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't far simple something like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
string me=("hello and goodbye");
int i,j, index=0;
char tmp;

for (i=0; i<me.length()+1; i++) 
    if (me[i] == ' ' || me[i] == '\0') {
        for(j=i-1;j>index;j--,index++) {
            tmp = me[index];
            me[index] = me[j];
            me[j] =tmp;
        }           
        index = i+1;
    }

cout << me;
return 0;
}
```

?

Complexity is O(n): each word is read twice (or, better, one and a half times): once since the program finds a space or a \0, then, in the nested for, the word is reversed. `index` indicates the word starting char.

Comment: Or just `std::reverse(me.begin()+index, me.begin()+i);` instead of the for loop. Plus or minus an out-by-one error on my indices there.

Comment: Thank you for the much shorter code.  I guess mine would also be O(n) for the same reason

Comment: Each word is read twice, not one and half. When you swap you read the word a second time (except the middle character of words with an odd number of characters) and it is always written once (minus one character when odd length, again.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a stack in between your input and output strings.  The stack's useful to hold the current word, and it does the reversing for you, too.  I'm not going to write the full code for it, but the algorithm is:

```
String output = ""
char Stack stack = []
while input.not_empty:
    char c = input.get_char
    if c == ' ':
        while stack.not_empty:
            output.put_char(stack.pop)
        output.put_char(c)
    else:
        stack.push(c)
while stack.not_empty:
    output.put_char(stack.pop)
return output
```

That'll give you O(n), and it's pretty easy to prove:

- Each character is read once (O(1))
- It's pushed onto the stack (at most) once (O(1))
- It's popped off the stack at most once (O(1))
- It's written once (O(1))

So: 4 * n * O(1), which is O(n).

Hope this helps!

PS:  If this is homework, people are more likely to help you if you tag it as such.